# Powershell LDAP query to get all groups, owners,members by OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I need to write a powershell script that will take in an OU
and return all the groups and their owners but if no owner then all the members

I have almost 0 powershell knowledge any help would be useful, I do that the active directory module installed

Comment: Simply asking wont help you. You have to try yourself first here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory ;
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*Your Group Name*"} -Properties Description,info | Select Name,samaccountname #| Export-Csv D:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
Get-ADGroupMember YourGroupName # to list members ;
```